# Other expressions for "to be the devil's advocate"?

Tags: phrase-requests, expressions

Is there another way or expression to say:

> He is the devil's advocate

I don't quite like this expression, and I don't know if it is a good idea to use it in a religious context.

Comment: One *plays devil's advocate*. You could say that someone who is saying something for the sake of argument is just *playing devil's advocate*.

Comment: Are Satanists offended by this phrase?  I've honestly been curious of this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could say you are doing something **for the sake of argument**.

But, really, "devil's advocate" is a familiar phrase that few people take exception to. In fact, it's even used by religious people. [For example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate),

> During the canonization process of the Roman Catholic Church, the Promoter of the Faith (Latin: promotor fidei), popularly known as the Devil's advocate (Latin: advocatus diaboli), was a canon lawyer appointed by Church authorities to argue against the canonization of the candidate.

If those religious worthies may use the term, I don't see anything preventing you from doing likewise.

Comment: In case this isn't clear, the term "Devil's Advocate" is religious in origin. It was eventually adopted for secular purposes, but it was created for a religious function - namely, the vetting process for sainthood. In fact, it is this religious dimension that gives the term such a rich etymology and meaning - the Advocate is performing due diligence in the service of ultimate good.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer @Robusto's response, but if you're still uncomfortable with the term, consider "***[opposition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opposition)***", "***[opposer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opposer)***", or "***[contrarian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian)***".

Comment: "Contrarian" is too loaded with negative connotations for this purpose, to my mind. (Though that could just be me)

Comment: @AndyBursh:  I agree that "[contrarian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian)" tends to be used in an unflattering way almost all the time--"devil's advocate" *can* be similarly unflattering.  However, it's the only noun form I could think of with the same meaning as the preposition and adverb "contra", which simply means "against" or "opposed to."

Comment: I like "contrarian". I only really know the term from finance, so I'm not familiar with the mentioned negative connotations, but the definition provided at the linked site will fit the requirement quite well in many, though not all, "devil's advocate" cases.

Answer (score 2):

I would use words like "dissenter," or even "critic." These are functions performed by the "devil's advocate."

Comment: I think "dissenter" and "critic" usually mean that they argue against something *because* they disagree. In my experience the "devil's advocate" usually argues against something *although* he agrees, i.e. he argues it to ensure that it can be defended or to check for weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate that you are playing Devil's Advocate, you can also use "for argument's sake" when beginning a contrary view. I am just supplying another way to phrase it if someone is uncomfortable with using the former expression.

Comment: Hi Anne; please note the accepted answer to this question (the first one, right below the question itself) offers "For argument's sake" as an alternative. In other words, this is a good, but duplicate, answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose 2 things to consider:
1. I agree with Joachim Sauer. I always thought that when someone is the "devil's advocate" not necessarily means that he is 100% opposed to whatever is presented to him. 
2. As to use it in a religious context, I think it will extremely awkward for a religious leader to use it or to become such. It is best to use an alternative expression: "I will be the final critic" "They have to convince me" Their argument must be very strong" etc. JF