# What do you call someone who likes controversial things?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you call a person who does/thinks the opposite of the crowd for just that reason?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70526/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-does-thinks-the-opposite-of-the-crowd-for-just-tha)

For example, there is an almost-normal person, but this person has a special quality, (s)he likes things that go against "normal people", for example he likes Hitler, but stating that will begin and endless debate about morals.

Hipster may be a word, but is there a better word for that?

Comment: Related questions: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39995/18655 and http://english.stackexchange.com/q/79125/18655

Comment: I think none of the current answers really answers the literal question being asked (although I see an answer has been accepted).  *Controversial* doesn't necessarily imply *contrarian* or *Devil's Advocate*.  If I like controversial things I'd interpret that to mean I like things where I'm likely to see lively debate or arguments, but I may like to sit back and watch and may not have any particular attachment to either viewpoint.

Comment: @Jim, I added  *controversialist* to my answer, which may answer the literal question.

Comment: "for example he likes Hitler, but stating that will begin an endless debate about morals" -- it seems 'normal' people do this all the time, only they don't "state that" because "that will begin an endless debate" TFIC.

Comment: I wish the answer was "a controvert" (like an introvert or an extrovert). But it's not.

Comment: My question came because there was this 9/11 and there are many conspiracy theories and many Osama supporters, I mentioned Hitler because because some people could go crazy given the date. Returning to the example, they admire Osama while most would get mad if they heard this pro-Osama person. But I thought it might be a psychological condition where you don't try, you just can't help it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From usage in general writing and esp., management literature, I would think of the term ***maverick***, usually a person who is given to thinking differently from the conventional/ popular. Often, not just differently but radically opposite to the accepted line of thinking.

Though [dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/maverick) define the term rather concisely in scope, you will see it used quite extensively in the media and also in management studies of personality.

"[...maverick thinking is necessary to survive especially in times of crisis, when the rules of engagement in business change and when you set big goals to achieve big things.](http://www.ecademy.com/node.php?id=141844) "

Many other references can be found on Google.

Comment: An unorthodox or independent-minded person.  
I think this is the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Answers to [question #70526](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70526/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-does-thinks-the-opposite-of-the-crowd-for-just-tha),   “What do you call a person who does/thinks the opposite of the crowd for just that reason?” include: *[contrarian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contrarian)*, *[individualist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/individualist)*, *loner*, *lone wolf*, and *lone hand*, and Fumblefingers mentioned  “nonconformist, renegade, maverick, rebel, radical, individualist, heretic, dissenter, dissident, iconoclast, loner, etc., etc.”

Note, wiktionary defines a *[contrarian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian)* as  “a person who expresses a contradicting viewpoint, especially one who denounces the majority persuasion”, and also shows a different sense for contrarian market analysts.

The word *[controversialist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/controversialist)* may be relevant; wiktionary defines this as “One who regularly engages in public controversies” and offers the example “Richard Dawkins has become a leading controversialist in a few areas.”

Answer (score 2):

[Contrarian](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contrarian):

> opposing or rejecting popular opinion or current practice:
>
> *the comment came more from a **contrarian** disposition than moral conviction*

[Wiktionary defines a contrarian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian) as:

> a person who expresses a contradicting viewpoint, especially one who denounces the majority persuasion

Comment: I would call them contrary. The question didn't specify a noun and I think contrary is a more common word than contrarian.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say [polemist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polemist) (or [polemicist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polemicist)), but I'm not sure how natural that sounds for native speakers.

Comment: *Polemist* I hadn't seen before, but  *polemicist* is well-known and mostly relevant.  I tend (without a basis I can pin down) to think of polemicists as bitterly engaging in controversy, but not necessarily “liking controversial things” as question title asks for.

Answer (score 1):

That might be [devil's advocate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/devil%27s%2Badvocate?q=devils+advocate)